# How to select more than one words in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, selection, visual-studio-2019

Usually we select multiple files using ctrl + left-mouse-button. Likewise is there a way to select multiple words at once in Visual Studio 2019. I have checked [MSDN article on selection](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdnstudents/2013/10/07/visual-studio-tips-selection-shortcuts-for-lazy-coders/) but my scenario is not listed there.

For instance, in following Image #1, I have selected React and in Image #2 I have selected ReactTable.

**Image #1**
[image]

**Image #2**

[image]

What I want is to select 'React' and 'ReactTable' these 2 words at once. Anyone know how can I select particular words from code at once?

Comment: What is the end goal by this selection? What will you do after that? Maybe there’s another way to do it

Comment: End goal is, it will save my lots of time. Many times in my project, I need to select multiple variabls which resides in different parts of code and if I select using tranditional (`double-click` on variable or `ctrl+shift+right-arrow`) method then it takes so much time. Thats why I asked question. Which way you were talking about?

Comment: But what do you do with them after? I mean, I don’t think you just select them and call it a day. Select, shut down Visual Studio. Why do you select them? What is the end goal with the variables?

Comment: I'll copy it and paste it in another code and start working on new code.

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy. Select first word normally (using double click or Holding Shift+Navigational Key(Arrow keys)) and then all other texts can be selected by holding down CTRL+ALT and using Left button of mouse. You can select text from different parts of code.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to select diferent variables at once that are randomly in the text Editor. you can hold Alt+Shift and select like i show it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x64Em.png)

Comment: You can save some time by Holding Ctrl and then you just need to click once with the mouse instead of double-click

Comment: I knew that shortcut and I have mentioned that in my question as well.